# Windows Profile Startup only black screen with CMD window. I messed with Regedit Command Processor AutoRun

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, boot, windows-registry

Stupidly I have messed with the Windows 10 Reg Key: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` following advice I found in this thread (I was suffering the exact issue described using Unity): https://answers.unity.com/questions/1675509/copying-assembly-from-tempunityenginetestrunnerdll.html

Long story short (short as possible!): I cleared the value of 'AutoRun' first. Too late I noticed the comment at bottom of his answer warning me of this very problem.

Now when Windows boots I get just a black screen and CMD window. I can type 'explorer' in and my computer functions as normal after that.

I have 2 profiles on my PC, the other one works fine. But I navigate to that same key in the working profile and the whole folder didn't exist in RegEdit. So I tried deleting on my broken profile but this didn't help. Before I deleted it I tried several values I found online, none of them seemed to have any effect at all.

So I really don't want to reinstall Windows, or even just delete this User Profile. But I have exhausted my knowledge on the matter and learned never to fiddle with RegEdit again. However since the profile works perfectly except the startup it seems to me there might be a way to still recover from this.

My guess with the limited knowledge I have is that the AutoRun value needs to contain 'Explorer.exe' or 'Startup.exe' or something like this. Any experts here can help me, I would be very grateful. Many thanks

NOTE:
I also tried the following:

1.sfc /scannow  = Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
2.Windows>Startup Repair = Could not fix any problems

Comment: It is unlikely you will be able to repair a damaged user problem. Very difficult and I have not seen it successfully done. Windows Repair install does not fix damaged profiles either. Copy what you need into the working profile and use all this as a learning experience.

Comment: OK thanks John. I feared as much but hoped there was something some genius could say what to fix :D. Thats my afternoon sorted then, figuring out what to keep and how to not lose passwords etc ... what fun :D

Comment: Well I have been lucky, I was just about to give up hope and then I noticed something so simple to try... System Restore. Luckily there was a restore point saved 4 days ago. I used it and seems to have fixed the problem. Perhaps this will create new problems, that I do not know yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to go in Windows 10 > Recover > Open System Restore and follow the steps to rollback to the restore point. I was fortunate that there was a point backed-up as I thought I had disabled this behaviour.